# How do I know if the request was received completely using TCP sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I have a multi-thread HTTP TCP server (written in Linux) and below is the function, that handles the client:

```
    void tcp_server::connection_handler(client* cl) {
    // add client to the clients <vector>
    mx.lock();

    cl->set_id(static_cast<int>(clients.size()));
    clients.push_back(*cl);
    cout << "New client with id " << cl->get_id() << " has been added to the clients list" << endl << endl;

    mx.unlock();

    char read_buffer[1024];
    ssize_t message_size;
    string received_message;
    while (accept_connections) {
        memset(&read_buffer, 0, sizeof(read_buffer));
        received_message.clear();

        message_size = recv(cl->sock, read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer) - 1, 0);

        if (message_size == 0) {
            // client disconnected
            cout << "Client with id " << cl->get_id() << " has been disconnected" << endl;
            close(cl->sock);

            //remove client from the clients <vector>
            mx.lock();

            int client_index = find_client_index(cl);
            clients.erase(clients.begin() + client_index);
            cout << "Client with id " << cl->get_id() << " has been removed from the clients list" << endl;

            mx.unlock();

            delete cl;

            break;
        }
        if (message_size == -1) {
            if (!accept_connections) {
                cerr << "Unable to receive message from client with id " << cl->get_id() << ". Server has been shut down. Stop receiving messages from this client" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cerr << "Error while receiving message from client with id " << cl->get_id() << endl;
            }
            cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
        }
        else {
            //message was received succesfully

            cout << "[Server] Client's message has been received" << endl;
            cout << "[Server] Client's message: " << endl;
            cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
            cout << read_buffer << endl;
            cout << "----------------------------" << endl;

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < message_size; i++) {
                received_message.push_back(read_buffer[i]);
            }

            string response_message = convert_client_message(received_message);

            if (send(cl->sock, response_message.c_str(), response_message.size(), 0) == -1) {
                cout << "[Server] Message sending to client with id " << cl->get_id() << " failed" << endl;
            }

            cout << "[Server] Server's response: " << endl;
            cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
            cout << response_message << endl;
            cout << "----------------------------" << endl << endl;

            cout << "[Server] Message has been sent to client" << endl << endl;
            cout << "============================" << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

How can you see, there's a buffer, that contains client's message, only is 1024 bytes, when request can be bigger than 1024 bytes.
So, the problem is: I need to know if request was received completely.
I was thinking about writing parser that might tell me if a full request was received, but I don't really know how to detect full request.

Comment: [Socket Programming -- recv() is not receiving data correctly](//stackoverflow.com/a/30655169)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was thinking about writing parser that might tell me if a full request was received, but I don't really know how to detect full request.

When implementing a protocol, it is recommended to actually take a closer look at the specification of the protocol.

If you read the [HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), you will realize that each [HTTP message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4) consists of headers and an optional body. The request is fully read once you have read the request headers and optional body. **The headers end with an empty line `\r\n` sequence**. Some HTTP methods, like `POST`, might have a body, in which case you'll find the length of the body in the `Content-Length` header, or you have to deal with the [chunked transfer encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1).

Please study the specification for more details.